# Would anyone know of good places in the NYC area which teach Biblical Hebrew?

Tags: hebrew, language, chinuch-education

I was not raised with any foundational Hebrew education. Most of the places that I've researched which teach Hebrew are all "Modern Hebrew" (spoken in Israel) courses and not Torah Hebrew (The language of the Torah and prayer)

I was curious if anybody knew of places in the NYC area which teach Torah Hebrew Courses for adults with little or no background.

Any other Torah Hebrew language resources are welcome as well.

Comment: Are you asking if they teach the Torah (which would be a way to learn the language of the Torah) or the language on its own (which might be a question about Hebrew and not Judaism)?

Comment: There are various universities in the area (Yeshiva University, JTS, NYU etc.)

Comment: I thought perhaps the OP would be able to use an online source, but was surprised that there are relatively no Jewish Biblical Hebrew courses online!

Comment: If you are looking just to learn the language, not "study Torah" itself, would you be open to a course run by a non-Jewish organization?